# Mailchimp RESTful API 3.0 HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: asp-classic, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to use the Mailchimp API version 3.0 with basic auth. I'm using Classic ASP.

The Json response is always: "API Key Missing".

```
Set HttpReq = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
HttpReq.open "GET", "https://us4.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/", False
HttpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
HttpReq.setRequestHeader "apikey", "xxxxxx"
HttpReq.send ""
Response.Write  HttpReq.ResponseText
Set HttpReq = Nothing
```

I'm sending it as a header.

What am I doing wrong..?

Comment: Try adding it to the URL i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595122/mailchimp-classic-asp-endpoint-error

Comment: Sorted! The header should be: HttpReq.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "apikey xxxxxx"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is:

```
HttpReq.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "apikey xxxxxx"
```

Comment: This is correct, but I had to make something else to get this working, after a lot of changes and investigation... I had to change MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP to MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0

Comment: I made a simple wrapper for Mailchimp API 3.0 in ASP with examples. I wish it's useful for somebody! https://github.com/javitoron/asp-mailchimp3

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use Basic Auth, you need to actually [follow the spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). You can build the header yourself using the wiki article as your guide, but the easiest thing is to just use your HTTP Library's built-in support for that. In your case, [this will probably help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712635/providing-authentication-info-via-msxml2-serverxmlhttp).

To roll your own, you need two pieces of information. The first is the username the second is the password. For MailChimp v3.0, the username can be anything. I tend to use 'apikey' as the username. The password is the API Key itself. Let's say my API Key is 'xxxxxxxxxx-yyy'. Now, you Base 64 Encode the string `apikey:xxxxxxxxxx-yyy`. That gives me `YXBpa2V5Onh4eHh4eHh4eHgteXl5`. Now the header I create is:

```
Authorization: Basic YXBpa2V5Onh4eHh4eHh4eHgteXl5
```

The method you're using will work, but is very custom to MailChimp and might confuse future visitors to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the question was based on #C but I had the same problem with java.(I am new to java so fell free to edit my code).

```
public String get(String url) throws IOException {
     HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
     String apiEncode = "apikey:9590e52MyAPI8-us9";
     String encoding = Base64.encodeBytes(apiEncode.getBytes());                     
     get.setHeader("Authorization","Basic " + encoding );
     HttpResponse response = http.execute(get);

    if (response.getEntity() != null) {
        return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8").trim();
    } else {
        throw new IOException(response.getStatusLine().toString());
    }
}
```